# Set the selector cursor to a new position in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, contenteditable

i've been making a text editor but i couldn't been able to get and set the "cursor" in a new position in the div with the content editable.

```
<form action="submitchapter.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group mb-3" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="Chapter Name" name="sname" value="No Title For The Chapter" required>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons shadow-sm">
        <button style="padding:0; border:0px solid white; background-color:white;" type="button" id="buttonbold"><i class="fas fa-bold" id="bold"></i></button>
        <input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />
    </div><br>
    <div class="containe shadow-sm" style="padding:20px; background-color:white;">
        <div class="content" contenteditable="true" name="content" id="content" role="textbox" spellcheck="false"></div>
    </div>
```

```
            var content = document.getElementById("content");

            var bold = document.getElementById("bold");
            var content = document.getElementById("content");
            $("#buttonbold").click(function(){
                content.focus();
                var valuelength = content.value.length - 4;
                content.setSelectionRange(content.value.length,valuelength);
            });
            var boldactive = false;
            $("#bold").click(function(){
                if (boldactive == false) {
                    var content1 = content.innerHTML;
                    content.innerHTML = content1 + "<b>";
                    boldactive = true;
                } else {
                    var content1 = content.innerHTML;
                    content.innerHTML = content1 + "</b>";
                    boldactive = false;
                }
            });
```

But nothing worked. I have tried with textarea too, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  if the code is too messy make it minimal and reproductible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` elements have no `value` property

```
$("#buttonbold").click(function(){
  content.focus();
  var valuelength = content.textContent.length - 4;
  content.setSelectionRange(content.textContent.length,valuelength);
});
```

.

---

`<div>` elements do not have a `setSelectionRange` method either,
so here is a solution to make this kind of selection for elements using the `contenteditable` property:

```js
const myDiv         = document.getElementById('my-div')
  ,   btSelectRange = document.getElementById('bt-select-range')
  ;
function setSelectionRangeCE(el, pos, len)
  { 
  el.focus();
  let range = document.createRange()
    , sel   = window.getSelection()
    ;
  range.setStart(el.firstChild, pos)
  range.setEnd(el.firstChild, pos+len)
  sel.removeAllRanges()
  sel.addRange(range)
  }
btSelectRange.onclick=_=>
  {
  setSelectionRangeCE(myDiv,2,5)
  }
```

```css
#my-div {
  margin:  1em;
  padding: .7em;
  width:   16em;
  height:  3em;
  border:  1px solid grey;
  }
button {
  margin:  1em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="my-div" contenteditable >hello world</div>

<button id="bt-select-range" > select range pos:2 len:5 </button>
```

Comment: And they don't have a `setSelectionRange` method either...

Comment: The "question" is "how to set the cursor position in a contenteditable div?" so yes, that's very part of the question...

Comment: this was the question: Set the selector cursor to a new position in contenteditable div. And yes, it answers to it.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you for your constructive criticism, I have changed my answer a second time, is that now correct?

Comment: yes better now.

Comment: @Kaiido no reward for this effort? (reputation points)